# Use Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, win-universal-app

I am trying to use Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc in my Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Application, but can't add the nuGet packages.

The Error says:

> Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0
>   (win10-x64-aot).
>
> Package restore failed for 'Temp1.WinUniversal'.
>
> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'Temp1.WinUniversal'

Does anyone know how I can use MVC in in a UWP Application? maybe any other libiry?

Comment: Why would you want to use an ASP.NET MVC library in a UWP application? What do you want from it?

Comment: You may want to try ASP.NET 5. Since it's based on .NET Core, there is a possibility it could work. I wouldn't bet on it though

Comment: @Lloyd Why should I not use an ASP.Net MVC library in a UWP application? I am new in MVC and just want to develop a clean MVC structure in my UWP Application. What else would you recommend?

Comment: If you want to develop clear structure use MVVM instead. It is something like MVC, but it is designed for non-web apps and xaml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the *pattern* MVC with the *implementation* of MVC for web pages/services on ASP.NET.

They're not the same. You can of course use the *pattern* MVC in UWP but *not* ASP.NET MVC. That makes no sense.

However for most desktop applications I think MVVM makes more sense, in which case you should use something like [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net.MVC runs on top of ASP.Net which runs on top of IIS (or other web servers) to host web pages.
Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is not IIS. It is a desktop platform for making desktop apps.